# Error: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, safari, navigator

I've created a script that sharing a image but when i try to share the image got this error:

`Error: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context.`

**Bug on**:
IOS 12/13 - Safari 12/13
**Works perfectly without bugs on**:
IOS 14 - Safari 14

**My code**:

```
$('.share-action-user').off('click');
$('.share-action-user').on('click', function(e){
   if (navigator.share) {
      var html = this.parentElement.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.document.body;
      html2canvas(html).then(canvas => {
         var a = document.createElement('a');
         a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
         a.download = 'ticket.jpg';

         fetch(a.href)
         .then(function(response) {
            return response.blob();
         })
         .then(function(response) {
            var file = new File([response], "ticket.jpg", {type: 'image/jpeg'});
            var filesArray = [file];
            shareFiles(filesArray);
         })
      });
   } else {
      window.alert('web share not supported');
   }
});
```